# httpd using high amount of memory?

Tags: wordpress, apache

On a t3.small Amazon EC instance, I'm running two wordpress websites. One is running WooCommerce and the other is just a plain Wordpress with the Avada theme.

After editing a few pages, I notice the memory usage going up and up and usually after about an hour, the server stops responding (out of memory and possible due to heavy swapping).

Running the following command for example shows;

```
ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB";}'

15.1328 MB
416.688 MB
527.73 MB
372.43 MB
543.508 MB
2.45703 MB
```

The apache server is running prefork with the following config;

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers          5
    MaxSpareServers         10
    MaxRequestWorkers       10
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

Any hints on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, my home page had a few images that were not loading via https which caused them to keep a few connections timing out which caused a high amount of connections to stay open.